# A problem that leads to a nodejs vulnerability

Tags: node.js, linux, server

I have a nodejs chat site

I noticed a stranger entering the site
With each login, the site restarts
When I opened the command line on the Linux server
These lines appeared to me
Is it a loophole or a problem?
what is the solution

```js
0|server   |  1: 0xa89e60 node::Abort() [node /root/server.js]
0|server   |  2: 0x9ade29 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [node /root/server.js]
0|server   |  3: 0xc7583e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node /root/server.js]
0|server   |  4: 0xc75bb7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node /root/server.js]
0|server   |  5: 0xe3f6d5  [node /root/server.js]
0|server   |  6: 0xe4027c  [node /root/server.js]
0|server   |  7: 0xe4dc0b v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node /root/server.js]
0|server   |  8: 0xe5190c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node /root/server.js]
0|server   |  9: 0xe15657 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRawWithAllocationSite(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::AllocationSite>) [node /root/server.js]
0|server   | 10: 0xe1be98 v8::internal::Factory::NewJSObjectFromMap(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::AllocationSite>) [node /root/server.js]
0|server   | 11: 0xff5165 v8::internal::JSObject::New(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSReceiver>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::AllocationSite>) [node /root/server.js]
0|server   | 12: 0xffeb18 v8::internal::JSDate::New(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSReceiver>, double) [node /root/server.js]
0|server   | 13: 0xd0bc91  [node /root/server.js]
0|server   | 14: 0xd0c726 v8::internal::Builtin_DateConstructor(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node /root/server.js]
0|server   | 15: 0x15046d9  [node /root/server.js]
```

I expect that it is a vulnerability that leads to a restart and the appearance of these lines
But I don't know yet how to solve this problem

Comment: Is that everything? No more output? Seems like a Memory issue: ```FatalProcessOutOfMemory``` You have a memory leak in your app. Not necessarily a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not enough memory to process the input.

First of all I would suggest to check if there is an input validation on the server side. You must have some settings to **limit the payload size**.

And then you need to figure out what IP addresses are sending those suspicious requests and **block those IP addresses**.

*As a last step you could try to add more memory to the working instance, or increase the number of instances (nodes) in your cluster. But more likely it will not help.*