# Linux server cache injection vulnerability

Tags: node.js

For a while now, I have been facing a vulnerability that fills up the storage space, causing the site to stop for a minute.

Even though I have set up express-rate-limit, to prevent leakage of requests.

But there is no use, the site still stops, and when I use the command line on the server, it shows me that the reason is that the storage memory is full.

In fact, it is a loophole through which the storage memory is filled. Someone stopped all my websites at once

How can I know how this is done or how the vulnerability is used?
How can I protect against this?

Please help, I am confused

```js
0|server   |  1: 0xa89e60 node::Abort() [node /root/server.js]
0|server   |  2: 0x9ade29 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [node /root/server.js]
0|server   |  3: 0xc7583e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node /root/server.js]
0|server   |  4: 0xc75bb7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node /root/server.js]
0|server   |  5: 0xe3f6d5  [node /root/server.js]
0|server   |  6: 0xe4027c  [node /root/server.js]
```

Comment: This looks very much like a duplicate of your previous post: [A problem that leads to a nodejs vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77527422/a-problem-that-leads-to-a-nodejs-vulnerability)

Comment: I blocked ip requests but it is of no use

Comment: I’m not quite sure how that statement significantly differentiates this question from your previous one to the point it justifies a brand new post.